# How to implement policy from BRE in orchestration to check if xml meet condition?

Tags: biztalk

I am working on Biztalk project where I have Orchestration with decide shape. 
in decide shape I check if one node of xml is "XXX".

```
> if(Code == "xxx"  ) 
>{
> Enable = true;
>}
>else 
>{
>Enable = false;
>
 }
```

Before decide shape, in expression shape is specified code. 
Where "Code" and "Enable" are variable. "Code" is xpath to specific value in schema. 
how can I create policy and replace that expression shape ?

what i should specify in policy? in " action" ?
thank you for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to pass your document and a .NET object to the rule.  You might have a .NET object like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class BreResult
{
    bool _enable;
    public bool Enable
    {
        get
        {
            return _enable;
        }
        set
        {
            _enable = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Compile this and add it to the GAC.  In your BRE policy, add the source document and the .NET class as objects.  In the `Actions` portion of the rule, drag over `BreResult.set_Enable`, and set it to True or False depending on the result of your rule.  Then add an Update and drag over `BreResult`.

In your orchestration, create a variable for your .NET class (`varBreResult`).  In an expression before calling BRE, you can do something like

```
varBreResult = new Namespace.Helper.BreResult()
```

After calling BRE, in your decide shape you can have

```
varBreResult.Enable == true
```

I've not had much luck with passing a .NET object from the Orchestration call shape that I originally linked, but if you call it from code it will work.  Here's an example of how to do that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995566.aspx